# Map from $R^2$ to $R^3$ onto and smooth.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I was doing a problem of differential geometry and I reduce the problem to the following question:

If $U \subset R^2$ and $V \subset R^3 $ open sets. Show there is not a map $f: U \rightarrow V$ surjective and smooth.

I am sure the below proposition is true but I don´t know how to prove it. I was thinking to use the inverse theorem but we don´t know anything about df. Also I was thinking to take tangent space but I don´t believe that the induce tangent map will be also surjective.

Comment: Do you know Sard's Theorem?

Comment: No, we haven´t seen that theorem.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't it the case that any map from  dimension n to dimension greater than n cannot be onto? I don't know if that is a theorem or not, but I am almost certain that the fact is true.

Comment: That is what we want to prove but I don´t know how to prove it.

Comment: @user79790: There are such maps of sets (since both sets have the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$). In fact there are continuous maps (google "space-filling curve" to get an example from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$). However, there can be no smooth map. This is a simple corollary of Sard's theorem. Any differential topology book should have a proof in it.

Comment: Ah, apparently my knowledge of geometry could use a refresher; I knew I should have taken topology...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof below uses some measure theory, but less than a proof of Sard's theorem would require.

---

**Claim**. Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ be a locally Lipschitz map. If   $n<m$, then $f$ is not onto.

*Proof*. Let $\mathcal H^n$ be the $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure. For every integer $k$ the set $B_k=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:|x|\le k\}$ has finite $\mathcal H^n$ measure. The restriction of $f$ to $B_k$ is Lipschitz, and it is easy to see that Lipschitz maps increase Hausdorff measure at most by some factor depending on the Lipschitz constant. Hence, $\mathcal H^n(f(B_k))<\infty$.

If $f$ were onto, then $\mathbb R^m=\bigcup_k f(B_k)$ would have $\sigma$-finite $\mathcal H^n$ measure. But the latter is false: $\mathbb R^m$ contains uncountably many disjoint sets of positive $\mathcal H^n$ measure, such as translates of an $n$-dimensional subspace. $\quad \Box$